# Family friendly escape room, 6 letter Cryptex

Tags: wordplay

The following is a puzzle of mine, I'm hoping to test it out a bit. It will be for a 6 letter cryptex to find the key inside the cryptex allowing you to exit a door in an escape room of mine.

Puzzle for a 6 letter Cryptex

> I am a well worded sentence,
>   With the intent to deceive.
>   Identify my title,
>   Only then can you leave.

Comment: Hi, and I second Omega Krypton in welcoming you to Puzzling.SE! Could you elaborate on where you found this puzzle, or if it is of your own creation? Thanks!

Comment: It Is one of mine, just hoping to test it out a bit. it will be for a Cryptex to find the key to exit a room in my escape room. I changed the wording a little, let me know

Comment: @Gamesguy looks great; it might be a good idea to give us the length of the cryptex, if you are looking to simulate the escape room. Up to you, of course.

Comment: Sorry i did not know there were multiple sized cryptex’s. It is a 6 letter cryptex

Comment: The clue will be posted in a cabinet with the cryptex with the key to get out of a room inside of the cryptex

Comment: are you sure the family tag fits? it refers to "A puzzle centred around kinship, family ties, ancestry, relatives, blood ties and other family bonds", instead of the puzzle being used as a puzzle among a family. Is this the case? if not, please change the tag to more suitable ones. thanks!

Comment: I see what your saying, I do my room at a family friendly event. Because of that I’m hoping the puzzles will be suitable for all ages thats why i tagged it as such. But i can change it.

Comment: Please check the tag wikis before using tags. Four of the five tags that you used do not apply to this question, and I'm not sure the fifth does as well. Tags are used based on the *content of the puzzle itself*, not based on the surrounding context.

Comment: @Gamesguy Can you please comment on whether my answer is on the right track?

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing the Cryptex itself (to check which letters are available), my first guess would be

> EXCUSE

```
I am a well worded sentence,  
With the intent to deceive.
```

> An excuse is not the real reason for something you do, but it's usually socially acceptable in content and politely worded. (Because otherwise, why bother with excuses.)

```
Identify my title,
Only then can you leave.
```

> One would usually use an excuse to leave, and "May I be excused" is a very polite way of asking if you are allowed to go.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd try "puzzle" and "riddle" if I had the cryptex in hand :-)